# Quickblox uploading a file in custom object

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, quickblox

I'm trying to upload a file in a custom object but it won't upload the file. The file in not even uploaded, and the "attachment" field on the db remains null.
If I'm trying to send the data without QBCOFile it will upload but the "attachment" field remains null.

my code:

```
    QBCOCustomObject *object = [QBCOCustomObject customObject];
    object.className = @"Custom";
    [object.fields setObject:@"blue" forKey:@"color"];
    QBCOFile *file = [QBCOFile file];
    file.name = @"Picture";
    file.contentType = @"image/png";
    file.data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(stone.picture);
    [object.fields setObject:file forKey:@"attachment"];

    NSMutableArray *customObjects = [NSMutableArray new];
    [customObjects addObject:object];
    [QBCustomObjects createObjects:customObjects className:@"Custom" delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wrong way,

look at this guide http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-ios#Files

you need the next:

1. Create an object of your class with file field
2. Upload a file to this field

Comment: Thank you Igor. I thought there's a shortcut so I can create the object and upload the image to the field on the same time. I guess that your way is better than mine; eventually I uploaded the file as content, took the URL I got and put it in an object's string field: [QBContent TUploadFile:file.data fileName:@"file_name"] contentType:@"video/quicktime" isPublic:YES delegate:self];